# Remove `about` from jquery Timeago strings

Tags: jquery, timeago

Does anyone know how to remove "about" prefix from [jquery.timeago.js](http://timeago.yarp.com/) output? e.g. if it says "about 1 minute ago", I want it to be just "1 minute ago".

There's some posts around here about dynamically changing the string, but it's not clear what's supported in recent versions or how to do this exactly.

Comment: [Datefuzz](https://github.com/arcanis/datefuzz) (a library of mine) allows to easily change the [translation table](https://github.com/arcanis/datefuzz/blob/gh-pages/jquery.datefuzz.js#L13) by passing a custom one as option. Maybe it can fit your use case.

Comment: Remove "about" from `strings` at `$.extend()` http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js , starting at line 46 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the localization. They have examples [here](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/tree/master/locales)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple change all the settings (it says so right in the docs)

```
jQuery.timeago.settings.strings.minute = "1 minute ago";
```